# I want to change how the multiline comment appears in my vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Alt + shift + A triggers multiline comment like this 
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/58QQL.png 

I want the multiline comment to appear like this 
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2cFy.png

I don't know how to describe this problem.

Comment: So you just want to add an `Enter` at the cursor position when you trigger a multiline comment?

Comment: Yes, and some whitespaces too. Can you help me with that ?